# PHP Insert to a specific table under a specific criteria

Tags: insert

Im new on programming in php so i need a little help here :'c

So as the title speaks. I already got 3 tables on my database (Named: List14, list15, list16)

I already created a html to input things on my database and now i want to ask for something that whenever I select the **radio button** "14" the data will go straight to "List14" table and when I select "15" the data will go to "List15".

Im using a simple php script but the script is for a single entry. 
"ex. the input will only go to list14 table only"

This is my php sample

```
<?php

define ('DB_NAME', 'testdb');
define ('DB_USER', 'root');
define ('DB_PASSWORD', '');
define ('DB_HOST', 'localhost');

$link = mysql_connect (DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD);

if (!$link) {
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}

$db_select = mysql_select_db (DB_NAME, $link);

if (!$db_select) {
    die ('Can\'t use' . DB_NAME . ': ' . mysql_error());
}

$value= $_POST ['loap'];
$value2= $_POST ['listdata1'];
$value3= $_POST ['listdata2'];
$value4= $_POST ['listdata3'];
$value5= $_POST ['listdata4'];
$value6= $_POST ['Landuse'];

$sql = "INSERT INTO list14 (loap, listdata1, listdata2, listdata3, listdata4, Landuse) VALUES ('$value', '$value2', '$value3', '$value4', '$value5', '$value6')";

if (!mysql_query($sql)) {
    die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
}

header( "refresh:3;url=liform.php" ); 
echo"Successfully added to database!!! Redirecting you back to list forms!!! Please wait.";

mysql_close();
?>
```

Any help will be very much appreciated. I know some if,else statement. I think it would be go through there.

Thank you! :)

Comment: Give some condition before inserting to db, like if($radio='14')

Comment: Thank you about this. I finally have the idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can define your table name in if condition as given below.

```
$sqlins = $_POST['rad']; // you radio button on html

if ($sqlins == "list14"){
    $table = "list14";
}else if ($sqlins == "list15"){
    $table = "list15";
}else{
    die('Error: No data selected'); // Stop execution
}
$sql = "INSERT INTO ".$table." (database columns) VALUES ('Textbox values');
mysql_query($sql);
```

Comment: Yes got this one :) but i prefer hiding my table names :) Anyway i like this style so i dont need to re-copy the query over again :)

Comment: By the way Geo Tom. I tried this method you have here but it doesnt insert eny data on any of my dbtables, List 14 or list 15 doesnt get the data

Comment: Could you please share the code so that I can check on the issue

Comment: Its okay now Geo Tom,  I just forgot to select something on radio button selection before hitting the submit button... Hihi.. Just my failure. :D

Answer (score 1):

Thank you @Geo Tom for giving me the idea.

I put something in my insert.php with this syntax

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO list14 ("database columns") VALUES ('Textbox values');
$sql2 = "INSERT INTO list15 ("database columns") VALUES ('textbox values')";

$sqlins = $_POST['rad']; /** My radio button on html

if ($sqlins == "list14"){
echo "Will saved to list14 Redirecting back to Previous Page!";
mysql_query($sql);
}else if ($sqlins == "list15"){
echo "Will saved to list15 Redirecting back to Previous Page!";
mysql_query($sql);
}else{
die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
}
```

If anything else is wrong with the codes please teach me a good idea. :) Thank you so much

Comment: oopps. its mysql_query($sql2) in line under "will saved to list15"